# go net/http response status 302 header location contains spaces interrupting the "redirection chain"

Tags: go, http-get

I am sending a http get request to a URL that starts a "redirection chain" by sending a response with `StatusCode 302`. The `response.header` as a Property called `Location` containing the URL that the get request should be redirected to. But if the URL contains spaces they won't be sanitaized by replacing them with %20 when using the go `http.get`, `http.client.get` and `http.client.do`. Causing the redirection process to be interrupted by a `Error 400 Bad Request` in my case.

Example:

URL in `response.header["Location"]`

```
https://domain.ex/demo?param1=I will cause this URL to break
```

should turn to

```
https://domain.ex/demo?param1=i%20will%20cause%20this%20url%20to%20break
```

Using `Chrome`, `Firefox` or `Powershell Invoke-Webrequest` works just fine, because they correct the invalid URL.

To fix it in my go program I needed to use a `http.RoundTripper` to intercept the redirection and sanitize the URL.

```
type LogRedirects struct {
    Transport http.RoundTripper
}

func (l LogRedirects) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    t := l.Transport
    if t == nil {
        t = http.DefaultTransport
    }
    resp, err = t.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    switch resp.StatusCode {
    case http.StatusMovedPermanently, http.StatusFound, http.StatusSeeOther, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect:
        LocationURL, _ := resp.Location()
        resp.Header.Set("Location", strings.ReplaceAll(LocationURL.String(), " ", "%20"))
    }
    return
}
```

and after wards I pass it to the `http.Client`

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: LogRedirects{},
    Timeout:   15 * time.Minute,
}
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Is it intended?
2. Is there a better way to fix this?

[Short cut to the net/http docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

Comment: Actually, the redirect target should not contain spaces in the first place. Thus sending a Location header where the URL contains spaces is wrong from start. These should have been sent as percent-encoded by the server. The problem is thus less in the client code not percent-encoding the space but in the server code adding these unencoded spaces in the first place.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what if the server still does it? Do you know any workarounds besides this one? The browsers and the powershell function both correct the URL that makes me wonder if that is should be something that is done by golang

Comment: I don't know of any workarounds. And actually I'd rather see browsers stop working around server side bugs like these. As long as "the big ones" work around brokenness they put pressure on other implementations to also add such workarounds - instead of putting pressure to fix the brokenness on the server side.